# finance using python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my code

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import datetime
import requests
import lxml
import yfinance as yf
import time
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def web_content_div(web_content,class_path):
    web_content_div = web_content.find_all('div',{'class': class_path})
    try:
        spans = web_content_div[0].find_all('span')
        texts = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
       
    except IndexError:
        texts = []
    
    return texts

def real_time_price(stock_code):
    
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code + '?p=' + stock_code 
   
    try :
        r = requests.get(url)
        web_content = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
        texts = web_content_div(web_content, 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)')
        if texts != []:
            price, change = texts[0],texts[1]
        else:
            price , change = [] , []
    
    
        texts = web_content_div(web_content,'D(ib) W(1/2) Bxz(bb) Pstart(12px) Va(t) ie-7_D(i) ie-7_Pos(a) smartphone_D(b) smartphone_W(100%) smartphone_Pstart(0px) smartphone_BdB smartphone_Bdc($seperatorColor)')
        if texts != []:
            for count, EX in enumerate(texts):
                if EX == 'Ex-Dividend Date':
                    EXdate = texts[count + 1]
        else:
            EXdate = []

        texts = web_content_div(web_content,'D(ib) W(1/2) Bxz(bb) Pend(12px) Va(t) ie-7_D(i) smartphone_D(b) smartphone_W(100%) smartphone_Pend(0px) smartphone_BdY smartphone_Bdc($seperatorColor)')
        if texts != []:
            for count, vol in enumerate(texts):
                if vol == 'Volume':
                    volume = texts[count + 1]
        else:
            volume = []


    except ConnectionError:
        price, change,EXdate,volume = [],[],[],[]

    return price, change, EXdate,volume

stock=['awr','dov','nwn','emr','gpc','pg','ph','mmm','ginf','jnj','ko','lanc','low','fmcb'
'cl','ndsn','hrl','abm','cwt','tr','frt','scl','swk','tgt','cbsh','mo','syy']


while(True):
    info = []
    col = []
    for stock_code in stock:
        time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
        time_stamp = time_stamp.strftime('%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S')
        price,change,EXdate,volume = real_time_price(stock_code)
        info.append(price)
        info.extend([change])
        info.extend([EXdate])
        info.extend([volume])
        time.sleep(1)
    col = [time_stamp]
    col.extend(info)
    df = DataFrame(col, columns=['price', 'change', 'EX-dividend-date', 'Volume'], index=stock)
    df.T

    print(col)
```

what i want to see is:

```
    price change ex-dividend-date volume
```

awr

dov

nwn

emr

etc...

then i fixed my code like this

```
    while(True):
        info_price = []
        info_change = []
        info_exdate = []
        info_volume = []
        for stock_code in stock:
            price,change,EXdate,volume = real_time_price(stock_code)
            info_price.append(price)
            info_change.append(change)
            info_exdate.append(EXdate)
            info_volume.append(volume)
            time.sleep(1)
        df = DataFrame(columns={"price":info_price,"change":info_change,"EX-dividend-date":info_exdate,"volume":info_volume},index=stock)
        df.T
    
        print(df)
```

but it print as....for example

```
    price change EX-dividend-date volume
```

awr       NaN    NaN              NaN    NaN

it just print nothing at all!!
so. what should i do get right output..
please help me. how can i handle this problem

I really appreciate your help:)!!!

Comment: Construct a dictionary and try again. For example `info['price'] = price` and so on. This way you can construct a dataframe straight from a dictionary without the need to specify columns.

Comment: thank you but it bit confusing....following error code: col.(info)
      
                                                                                   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The error is telling you the shape of the index doesn't match the shape of the data. It looks like you're attempting to have your data be a 2D array with 1 element that has a length of 16, while also passing in an index that has a length of 4 and 4 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stock=['awr','dov','nwn','emr','gpc','pg','ph','mmm','ginf','jnj','ko','lanc','low','fmcb'
'cl','ndsn','hrl','abm','cwt','tr','frt','scl','swk','tgt','cbsh','mo','syy']


while(True):
    info_timestamp = []
    info_price = []
    info_change = []
    info_exdate = []
    info_volume = []
    for stock_code in stock:
        time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
        time_stamp = time_stamp.strftime('%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S')
        price,change,EXdate,volume = real_time_price(stock_code)
        info_timestamp.append(time_stamp)
        info_price.append(price)
        info_change.append(change)
        info_exdate.append(EXdate)
        info_volume.append(volume)
        time.sleep(1)
    df = DataFrame({"timestamp":info_timestamp,"price":info_price,"change":info_change,"EX-dividend-date":info_exdate,"volume":info_volume},index=stock)
    df.T
```